# Converting commandline argument to string in C

Tags: c

I am new to programming. I want to take one commandline argument which is a filename and open that particular file and copy the contents to another file. I don't know how to convert the commandline argument to a string or file pointer. I checked strcpy and std::string which I found online but it didn't work. Please help me. I have pasted my code below

```
    #include<string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    void main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    char *inp;
    strcpy(inp,argv[1]);
    FILE *fp;
    char str[5];
    //printf("Enter the file name:");
    //scanf("%s",fname);

     if ((fp= fopen(inp, "r")) == NULL) {
     printf("cannot open file");
     exit(1);
     }
     FILE *fp1;
     fp1=fopen("out.txt","w+");
     while(!feof(fp)) {
     fgets(str,4,fp);
     printf("%s",str);
     fprintf(fp1,"%s",str);
      }

     fclose(fp);
      fclose(fp1);
      }
```

Comment: Just use `fopen(argv[1], "r")`. The `strcpy` won't work unless `inp` points to valid memory, e.g. `char inp[100]` or `char *inp = malloc(100)`. Also, don't use `while(!feof(fp))`. Instead use `while(fgets(str,4,fp)!=NULL)`.

Comment: `std::string` is C++, so that won't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the wrong way I checked for the EOF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `char *inp = argv[1];`?

Or better yet:

```
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

---

The problem with your code is this:

```
char *inp;
strcpy(inp,argv[1]);
```

You're copying `argv[1]` into `inp`, but you have no idea what `inp` points to. If you really want to go that route, you have to allocate memory for `inp`.

```
char *inp = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1); /* allocate enough for the string and null-terminator */
strcpy(inp,argv[1]); /* copy the contents */
```

Just remember to `free()` afterwards.

P.S. **Never** use `while(!feof(fp))`. Just use `while(fgets(str,4,fp))`. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) for more info.